# Keyboard shortcut to Insert 'Today's Date' in SharePoint 2010

Tags: date-time, shortcut

Does anyone know if there is a keyboard shortcut to insert 'Today's Date' in a Date field in SharePoint 2010? I've looked at the Microsoft Office [SharePoint 2010 Keyboard Shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/keyboard-shortcuts-HA010369395.aspx#BM02) and I do not see one. Just wondering if someone found a way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if there is such a shortcut. I just tried ctrl + ; which is for Excel and Alt-Shift-D which is for Word - neither works.

"Today's Date" can be set as the default in the field definition, which might help your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would have to be custom. You would have to bind an event to that particular control you are using. You could try using:

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

The syntax according to the repository is:

```
// e.g. replace '$' sign with 'EUR'
$('input.foo').bind('keyup', '$', function(){
  this.value = this.value.replace('$', 'EUR');
});
```

You can also set a default value for the date field with Sharepoint OOB. When you specify a date field (ie. Start Date site column) click on the 'List Settings' for that list.

Under the section 'Columns' select the date field you want to set the date, and under 'Additional Column Settings' there is an option for a 'default value' called 'Today's Date'.